# C++ Polymorphic Behavior: swapping derived pointer types

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, dynamic-memory-allocation

Observe the following code:

```
class A { public: virtual void Foo() = 0; int Bar; };

class B : public A { public: B( float X ); void Foo(); private: float X; };

class C : public A { public: C( float Y ); void Foo(); private: float Y; };
```

Now, in some function let's say I do this:

```
A*& pToA = pToDerived; // allocated as A* pToDerived = new B( ... );

pToA     = pToC; // allocated as A* pToC = new C( ... );
```

Is this valid? If so, will it cause a memory leak even though `pToA` is a reference to a pointer of `pToDerived`?

**SSCS**

Assume that `Node` has, say, 2 or more types which derive from it. This is a snippet from a linked list I'm implementing at the moment, which will likely require polymorphism in order to work properly, as it's not meant to be generic. `newnode` is the argument passed to an insert function.

```
    Node* iNode;

    for( iNode = mStart; iNode != mEnd; iNode = iNode->Next )
    {
        if ( iNode->Key == k ) // Replace current node with newnode
        {
            newnode->Next = iNode->Next;
            newnode->Prev = iNode->Prev;

            *iNode        = *newnode;

            delete newnode;

            return;         // We're done, so we quit.
        }
    }   

    // Node doesn't alreay exist, so we add it.

    Node*& uglyhack = mEnd;

    iNode->Next   = newnode;
    newnode->Prev = iNode;
    uglyhack      = newnode;
```

Comment: The code you provide is not sufficient to say whether there is a meamory leak or not. You need to provide a simplistic self compilable sample.

Comment: I updated my question, sorry about lack of clarity.

Comment: @about: It looks like you just want `Node*`, not `Node*&` (I can't really see why anyone would want a reference to a pointer). Also, is this for an academic reason? C++ already comes with a linked-list implementation, `std::list`.

Comment: (Also, it looks (given the Key comparison) that you are implementing an associative container (e.g. `std::map`) rather than a sequence container, like a list. (If so, you should use an associative container data structure, like a hash table or binary tree, not a linked list) You are aware that a linked list is about the poorest performing data structure for most any application, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following:

```
// See http://codepad.org/8mG6YiLy
class A { public: virtual void Foo() = 0; int Bar; };

// Added definitions for these so that this would compile
class B : public A {
    public: B( float x ) : X(x) {}
    virtual void Foo() {} // Once virtual, always virtual
    private: float X;
};

class C : public A {
    public: C( float y ) : Y(y) {}
    virtual void Foo() {}
    private: float Y;
};

int main()
{
    A* pToDerived = new B(3.14);
    // pToDerived -> B

    A*& pToA = pToDerived;
    // pToDerived -> B
    // pToA IS pToDerived

    A* pToC = new C(2.718);
    // pToDerived -> B
    // pToC -> C
    // pToA IS pToDerived

    pToA = pToC;
    // pToDerived -> C
    // pToC -> C
    // pToA IS pToDerived
    // One object of type B no longer has pointers pointing to it
}
```

This code leaks two objects -- one of type `B` (which happens at the `pToA = pToC` statement) and one of type `C` (which happens when `main` returns). The "reference" in this case doesn't actually enter into much of play here. In C++, references are just aliases for some other object. You cannot "reseat" them. That is, once a reference references something, it can never reference anything else ever again.

In this case, when you created pToA, you created a reference to the pointer -- the pointer in this case being `pToDerived`. Making this reference has no effect on memory managment or responsability of some code to call `delete` in the right place whatsoever.

Comment: Does this mean that in the snippet I posted that `uglyhack` will then leak memory?

Comment: @about: It means in the snippet you posted, that the pointer `mEnd` gets set to the same value as the pointer `newnode`. I don't know what a "leak" means in this case because it isn't clear who owns what memory in your example code. Certainly, making it a reference is not buying you anything. You can get rid of the reference entirely and just make the last line in your code be `mEnd = newnode;`, and the code would mean the same thing. (Which is what Vaughn's answer says)

Answer (score 3):

This is the same as doing

```
pToDerived = pToC;
```

There's nothing inherently wrong with that.  It will leak memory only if you never delete the objects, just like usual.

In your updated code, you could just do:

```
iNode->Next   = newnode;
newnode->Prev = iNode;
mEnd          = newnode;
```

and it would be the same.

Comment: +1 because this is correct -- but I don't really think it helps the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on that last bit -- so, because `iNode->Next` and `newnode->Prev` are already taken care of (i.e., set to point to their new addresses), setting `mEnd` shouldn't cause any issues?

Comment: @aboutblank: There's nothing particularly wrong there, but I'm not sure the role of mEnd is clear.  In your loop, it looks like mEnd is a special node that marks one-past-the-last node, since the loop never checks the mEnd node.  However, when you insert the new node, mEnd is being set to that node, so it appears that mEnd is meant to be the last node and not the one-past-the-last node.